# Why create MFC dialog wizard not includes resources.h

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have created MFC dialog form resource. After I ask Form Wizard to create class for this resource it generates header and cpp file correctly except one thing - my class does not recognize control ID that appears in class code like ID_BLABLABLA. After including resource.h - everything goes fine. But why wizard doesn't do it automatically?

This is dialog header:

```
#pragma once


// dlg4 dialog

class dlg4 : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(dlg4)

public:
    dlg4(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~dlg4();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG2 };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

dialog cpp:

```
// dlg4.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "dlg4.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// dlg4 dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(dlg4, CDialogEx)

dlg4::dlg4(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(dlg4::IDD, pParent)
{

}

dlg4::~dlg4()
{
}

void dlg4::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(dlg4, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// dlg4 message handlers
```

Answer (score 1):

The wizard includes the app class h file. The app class h file includes resource.h

It is quite reasonable for you to remove the include of app.h and replace it with resource.h

Comment: I have added wizard generated source. Where is app.h?

Comment: app.h means <yourappname>.h and it is in your project and it contains the class definition of your app class, which is derived from CWinApp or CWinAppEx.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The #include is in the .cpp, not the .h. The `enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG2 };` line does generate an error from the macro's definition not being in scope. For the main dialog that's not too much of an issue thanks to the order of generation (resource.h is included before the only yourmaindlg.h inclusion), but it is a frustrating oversight for other dialogs.